# How do I detect when a UIActionSheet has been dismissed?

Tags: iphone, uiactionsheet, dismiss

I'm pretty new to iPhone dev, so any help is appreciated.

I am creating an action sheet within a function and adding it to the current view. I have the sheet delegate as 'self' and the action sheet is not retained. Is there a function like the datePicker's didSelectRow? Something like "didDismissWithButtonAtIndex" or something that lets me detect when an action sheet is closing?

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UIActionSheetDelegate method `– actionSheet:didDismissWithButtonIndex:` is what you're looking for.  From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIModalViewDelegate_Protocol/UIActionSheetDelegate/UIActionSheetDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIActionSheetDelegate/actionSheet:didDismissWithButtonIndex:):

> #### actionSheet:didDismissWithButtonIndex:
>
> Sent to the delegate after an action sheet is dismissed from the screen.
>
> ```
> - (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
> ```
>
> **Parameters**
>   *actionSheet*
>   The action sheet that was dismissed.
>
> *buttonIndex*
>   The index of the button that was clicked. The button indices start at `0`. If this is the cancel button index, the action sheet is canceling. If `-1`, the cancel button index is not set.
>
> **Discussion**
>   This method is invoked after the animation ends and the view is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSLog(@"actionsheetvisible %@", actionSheet.isVisible?@"YES":@"NO");
```

Use the isVisible property.